# Using a function for calling sql server from r

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, rstudio

I have the following code

```
res<-function(y) {
data <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "select count([respondent serial]) from data1 
where [variable]= y")
print(data)
}
```

dbhandle is the connection established to sql server.

Now if i pass res(gender) am not getting results as i would normally get with a select statement in SQL.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind to include *all* the necessary package you are using (eg. RODBC?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the string inside the query does not understand that `y` is a variable. Hence `paste0()` is here to help:

```
res<-function(y) {
    data <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, paste0("select count([respondent serial]) from data1 
where [variable]=", y))
  return(data)
}
```

You can call the function by using  `res("gender")`.

## EDIT

In order to pass a numeric value, you can do:

```
res2<-function(y) {
    data <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, paste0("select count([respondent serial]) from data1 
where [week number] =", y))
  return(data)
}
```

You can check this out as well: `res2(201752)`

Comment: What if i want to pass a number and not string? Example:where [week number] = 201752. Paste0 in this case will not work? is there anyway to make this work

Comment: `y` can be literally anything when it comes to argument of a function. you can have a single digit, or a vector of numbers, a data.frame/data.table or a list. depends on what you do with it afterwards. I edited the example adequately